# th's width in thead doesn't match td width of tbody

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to empty the content of my table td, to make a loading and then show latest fetched data, but the problem is the thead seem have some flickering issue, as the width of thead is affected when tbody data is gone.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/nLrpbz9r/1/

Comment: If you mean that the width reduces (rather than flickers) that is because there is now no content and the table and cell widths are rendered according to their content. You could set minimum, or specific, widths to prevent this.

Comment: This is normal behaviour. If you want to keep the same width, use a fixed width value ( doesn't have to be in pixels, just relative to some element that isn't the content ) instead of letting the table adjust itsself to the cell with the longest content.

Comment: @Shilly can't use fixed width at all, the length of my data is from the server

Comment: But you have control over the css. So if you put wordwrap on the cells and put a fixed width on the column, the text will span multiple lines inside the cell if it's too long.

Comment: @Shilly example?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal... `display: none` elements are not involved in table width calculation. You can use `visibility: collapse` instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {

    const $tb = $("tbody");
    const new_visibility = $tb.css("visibility") === "visible" ? "collapse" : "visible";
    $("tbody").css({
      "visibility": new_visibility
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle tbody</button>

<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>john wesley</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately... when you insert new data in tbody, the widths will change depending on content. There is no good solution except using a fixed layout table.

Comment: hmm if it's ajax call don't think I can simply do visibility hidden, I have to rerender the data.

Comment: Of course, you need to set reasonable widths on table columns. If you don't then table will adjust it's size depending on content and it will flicker.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this two attribute which I set, we'll solve your problem:

```
table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The last two lines fix the width of each td width the value you want ( Instead of 200 px and it's better to set it by percent value to support the responsibility)  and the last line just put the text in center position. If you press the button, the Header cells will not change.

Comment: fixed width just won't work, my data is dynamic length

Comment: Ok! So You can min-width to keep the td width by a fix value. However setting the width width a value such as 100% keep the width based on the parent element and the value of text between td tag.

Answer (score 0):

add something like `table th {min-width: 100px;}` to your CSS.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    const tb = $('tbody').clone()
    if ($(tb).length > 0) {
      $('tbody').hide()
    }
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

table th {min-width: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>john wesley</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Hide tbody</button>
```